# SSRS 2005: How do I create a collapsible Text Field in Table?

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have a batch detail report in SSRS 2005, the left most column is an NTEXT SQL field. I need to show the field in the report either as:
1). A collapsible text box so users can view detail in the field by clicking the expansion control OR
2). As a tool tip, so when users hover over the column, they can view the full detail

I can find code to collapse or expand all columns (i.e. the entire row) but not for a single text box in a table.

Any assistance greatly received, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to make a collapsible text box in SSRS, but there *is* a ToolTip property for text boxes - just select the Text Box, then select the required value for the ToolTip property from the dropdown list of expressions in the Properties window.

The tool tip is only displayed in browsers, not in preview mode in the SQLServer BIDS report designer (as far as I can tell).